# Sum generic type to a double

Tags: java, generics

I need to implement a graph that will have a generic type elements as nodes, and generic type elements as labels of the edges. When labels are of type Double I need to be able to calculate graph's weight.

```
public class Graph<V, T> {
  ...

  public Double graphWeight() {
    Double sum = 0;

    for every label T weight {
        sum = sum + weight;
    }

    if(!directed) sum /= 2;

    return sum;
  }
}
```

Can this be done somehow?

Comment: use ``instanceof`` to find out if ``weight`` is of type ``Double``, then cast it.

Comment: Create a extension of `Graph` which defines the constraints as `String` and `Double`, it only makes sense to have `weight` when `T` is a numeric value

Comment: I fail to see why you would rather use generics than interfaces unless there is a need for strict enforcement of what type of nodes and edges the Graph will hold... But even so it seems like more of a hassle than the alternative.

An interface allows you to create different implementations of the nodes and edges to suit your needs.

Comment: @TiagoRedaelli, it's an assignment, so I'm unfortunately forced to do it like that.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm unfortunately forced to implement it this way

Comment: @f1sh, I tried it before, and it didn't compile, I must have messed something up. Now tried it again and it worked.. So thanks

Comment: @Sepfins So you can't do something like `Graph<String, Double>`, that would allow you to use part of dasblinkenlight's answer as well, where the "calculation" is delegated

Answer (score 3):

Pass and store an instance of [`DoubleFunction<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleFunction.html) in the constructor of the graph. Then use the stored instance in the loop:

```
public class Graph<V, T> {
  ...
  private final DoubleFunction<T> getWeight;
  public Graph(DoubleFunction<T> getWeight) {
    this.getWeight = getWeight;
  }
  public double graphWeight() {
    double sum = 0;
    for every label T weight {
        sum = sum + getWeight.apply(weight);
    }
    if(!directed) {
        sum /= 2;
    }
    return sum;
  }
}
```

Instances of the graph are created like this:

```
class Edge {
  ...
  public double weight() {
    ..
  }
}
...
Graph<Vertex,Edge> graph = new Graph<>(Edge::weight);
```

Comment: Can this be done if I don't have an "Edge" class, but my graph is implemented as HashMap<V, HashMap<V,T>>? Sorry, I just have never seen such stuff. And thanks.

Comment: @Sepfins Assuming that you would like to "interrogate" `HashMap<V,T>` for a `T`, where would the key of type `V` come from? Generally, though, you can use a lambda: `Graph<Vertex,Edge> graph = new Graph<>(w -> w.callThatExtractsDoubleGoesHere());`

Comment: @Sepfins, You can use an adjecency matrix to represent the weight between nodes if you don't have an Edge class: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I don't know if I undestood correctly, but "interrogation" goes something like `map.get(elem1).get(elem2)` where elem1 and elem2 are bothelements of type `V`. But in case of `graphWeight()` I just iterate through both HashMaps by using `values()`.

Comment: @Sepfins If `T` in `HashMap<V, HashMap<V,T>>` is a numeric type, such as `Double`, `Integer`, or `BigDecimal`, you can write `Graph<Vertex,BigDecimal> graph = new Graph<>(bigDec -> bigDec.doubleValue());`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion from me for what it's worth. It uses an adjacecny matrix to represent the weight which can either be an integer or a double (not sure why anyone would want this) and then a list of vertices for the nodes.

Still anything more than this should really be using interfaces for V and E.

```
public class Graph <V, E> {
    private List<V> vertices;
    private E[][] adjMatrix;

    public void setVertices(List<V> nodes) {
        vertices = nodes; 
    }

    public void setAdjacecnyMatrix(E[][] adjMatrix) {
        this.adjMatrix = adjMatrix;
    }

    public Object getNode(int index) {
       return vertices.get(index);
    }

    public boolean hasEdge(int srcs, int dest) {
        for (int v = 0; v < vertices.size(); v++) {
            if (adjMatrix[srcs][dest] instanceof Integer && (Integer) adjMatrix[srcs][dest] > 0)
                return true;
            if (adjMatrix[srcs][dest] instanceof Double && (Double) adjMatrix[srcs][dest] > 0)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public double graphWeight() {
        double sum = 0;
        int numV = vertices.size();
        for (int s = 0; s < numV; s++) {
            for (int v = 0; v < numV; v++) {
                if (adjMatrix[s][v] instanceof Double) {
                     sum += (Double) adjMatrix[s][v];
                }
                else if (adjMatrix[s][v] instanceof Integer) {
                    sum += (Integer) adjMatrix[s][v];
                }
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Graph<String, Double> g = new Graph();
    String[] nodes = {"A", "B", "C"};
    Double[][] adjMatrix = {
        {0., 1., 3.},    
        {1., 0., 2.},     
        {3., 2., 0.}};
    g.setVertices(Arrays.asList(nodes));
    g.setAdjacecnyMatrix(adjMatrix);
    System.out.println("g1: " + g.graphWeight());
    Graph<String, Integer> g2 = new Graph();
    Integer[][] adjMatrix2 = {
        {0, 1, 4},    
        {1, 0, 2},     
        {4, 2, 0}};
    g2.setVertices(Arrays.asList(nodes));
    g2.setAdjacecnyMatrix(adjMatrix2);
    System.out.println("g1: " + g2.graphWeight());
}
```